# How do I use a floor nailer near the wall?

Tags: flooring

I have the floor nailed down in the entire room , except for the last seven courses. The pneumatic floor nailer can't get any closer than that without the mallet hitting the wall. Do I really have to pre-drill and hand-nail the last seven courses?
I'm using a [Porter-Cable FCN200 Pneumatic Flooring Cleat Nailer](http://www.portercable.com/Products/ProductDetail.aspx?ProductID=11531).

[image]

Comment: Can you rotate it to be at right angles to the wall? Then that would just leave the corners.

Comment: @ChrisF Rotate the nailer? Or the flooring? I can't see how it would work either way.

Comment: The idea was that you'd be parallel to the wall (if that was possible). However, I see from the image that that probably wouldn't work.

Comment: One of the mfg selling points is "Non-marring base allows user to drive fastener close to wall".  Maybe you're as close as they mean, but have you checked the manual for tips?

Comment: Thanks. The manual does not help with this question.

Comment: Find it hard to believe that someone hasn't come up with a flooring nailer for the last 2 rows. Seems like some system of small steel wedges in a hammering sleeve could solve the physics of 45 degree angle power transfer.

Answer (score 8):

Usually you can hand toenail all but the last two rows, thus hiding the nails. Pre-drill pilot holes just above the tongue (same angle and placement as nailer would have done) and set the nails. You can use a wedge and blocks to tighten and hold the slats for nailing.  The last couple of rows should be glued and face nailed. Counter sink the nails and fill with a matching filler. If the floor is prefinished, then the manufactured probably offers a matching filler.  If it is unfinished, be sure to use a stain-able filler.

Comment: I used this technique, but I only face nailed the last row so I could hide the nails under the shoe molding.

Comment: As long as you get a swing with the hammer, getting down to last row is great.  I use the side of the hammer and try to get to the last row also.

Comment: I should've mentioned that the base trim wasn't up either, so I had a little bit extra clearance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you will have to hand-nail.

Comment: although you can probably use the nailer for one or two more courses - use the back of the hammer, and hit straight down.

Comment: Thanks. The manual does not help with this question, but it does say _not_ to use the back of the mallet.